# Several entities targetting the same table on table split

Tags: entity-framework

The error description is the following :

*"The entity types 'DocTypeA' and 'DocTypeB' cannot share table 'DocMain' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them."*

I don't see how I can solve this problem...

The situation is quite simple : I have 3 tables. Let's say that those tables are meant to store info about documents. There are 2 types of documents. So the DB design is to store the common information in a base table (DocMain), and accordingly to the type of document storing the specific information in the table DocTypeA or the table DocTypeB.

In my domain model, I've created one entity class for each document type (with the properties of the main table and the specficic one). I have 2 **EntityTypeConfiguration** to map each one to the 2 corresponding table (the main table and one of the 2 type specific).

If I have only 1 mapping, everything works fine. If I add the second mapping involving the same main table, I have got this error.

Is there a EF limitation I'm not aware of, or is this a bad design ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd that you are trying to store Documents in two different database tables. That is not standard database design.

One common approach would be that "Documents" would be a single database table and if you want to distunguish between the types of documents stored in that table, you could simply add a 'Type' column to the table which could be a foreign key to a 'Types' table.

If you are able to simplify your database design in this manner, you will be able to avoid this error from EF.

Comment: This DB Scheme is a mess I know. But, you know, things are the way they are. I'm not able to change this situation easily since there a lot of other applications using this DB.